# How can I launch android's email activity with an attachment attached in the email?

Tags: android

In my android, how can I launch android's compose email activity with an attachment attached?

Answer (score 9):

Just launch an intent with the following structure:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"to@example.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "the subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("the content"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/file.ext"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Notice that I'm using the complete path to the file: `"file:///sdcard/file.ext"`. Also, take into account that you can share files that you have saved into the SDCard only (otherwise, the email client will ignore the file).

Comment: oooh the file:/// thing is why it had never worked for me.  awesome!

Comment: now it would be good if somebody gave solution that involved file from memory... thanks anyway man ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "from memory"?

Comment: @Cristian I guess he is talking about **Mobile Internal Memory** instead SDCard